# how to revert the pushed changes in VScode?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

accidentally I pushed the changes before completely finish it.

now I want to revert the changes.. how can I do that?

Comment: i think this can help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit?rq=1 :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few methods in the post that @carolina pointed to.... however, I do not see the simplest 2 if it is a feature branch that no one else is working on:

## delete the remote branch

```
git push some-remote :the-branch # make sure to use the colon
```

## Push a different commit to the branch

```
git push some-remote -f $( git merge-base HEAD the-upstream-branch ):the-branch
```

That will push the revision from the upstream branch that the current branch started from.